# error "Cannot return to provided redirect_uri" in chrome extension using stackapp auth 2.0

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

I follow the tutorial here https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_identity and use the api here https://developer.chrome.com/apps/identity but with no luck. Could anyone point out is anything wrong in this code?

```
function onGoogleLibraryLoaded() {
    var redirect_uri = chrome.identity.getRedirectURL("http://qqibrow.github.io");
    var full_url =  "https://stackexchange.com/oauth/dialog?client_id=4716&redirect_uri=" + redirect_uri;
    console.log(redirect_uri);
    console.log(full_url);
    chrome.identity.launchWebAuthFlow({
        'url': full_url,
        'interactive': true
    }, authorizationCallback);
}

var authorizationCallback = function (data) {
    // should print out redirect_uri with auth_token if succeed.
    console.log(data);
};

// manifest.json
// ...
"permissions": [
    "activeTab",
     "identity",
    "https://ajax.googleapis.com/",
      "https://stackexchange.com/*",
        "https://stackexchange.com/oauth/*",
        "http://qqibrow.github.io/*"
  ],
   "web_accessible_resources": [
        "http://qqibrow.github.io/*",
        "https://stackexchange.com/*",
  ],
  // ...
```

If i try https://stackexchange.com/oauth/dialog?client_id=4716&redirect_uri=http://qqibrow.github.io it does work. But with above code, I always got a error page from stackexchange, saying that:

`Application Login Failure error description: Cannot return to provided redirect_uri.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a creative usage of [`chrome.identity.getRedirectURL()`](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/identity#method-getRedirectURL).

It does not allow you to redirect to an arbitrary domain; you can provide a path, but the domain for `chrome.identity` will be `https://<app-id>.chromiumapp.org`.

So, your call returns `https://<app-id>.chromiumapp.org/http://qqibrow.github.io` which is not a valid URL, and your auth fails.

I recommend re-reading the [`launchWebAuthFlow` documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/identity#method-launchWebAuthFlow).

Comment: do u imply that I should set `https://<app-id>.chromiumapp.org/` as my OAuth Domain in my application configuration, in this case, the stackexchange app?

Comment: As long as you want to use `chrome.identity` - yes.