# Cannot return to provided redirect_uri

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I m having an error when trying to build a chrome extension with oauth2 and chrome.identify.

It doesn't work for and I m having the following error :

```
Application Login Failure
An error occurred while login into an application.

Error Details

error description: Cannot return to provided redirect_uri
```

With the following code :

```
const id = '1234'
const key = 'key'
const scope = 'read_inbox,no_expiry'
const request_uri = 'https://stackexchange.com/oauth/dialog'
const redirect_uri = chrome.identity.getRedirectURL('oauth2')
const requestUrl = `${request_uri}?client_id=${id}&scope=${scope}&redirect_uri=${redirect_uri}`
chrome.identity.launchWebAuthFlow({
  url: requestUrl,
  interactive: true
}, url => {
  console.log('redire' + url)
})
```

It seems that the application tries to redirect on the following :

```
https://hipaoikehndjdcpknmnofjbhfjmonnem.chromiumapp.org/oauth2
```

but it doesn't work...

Any idea ?

My manifest :

```
{
  "name": "__MSG_appName__",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "description": "__MSG_appDescription__",
  "icons": {
    "16": "images/icon-16.png",
    "128": "images/icon-128.png"
  },
  "default_locale": "en",
  "background": {
    "scripts": [
      "scripts/chromereload.js",
      "scripts/background.js"
    ]
  },
  "permissions": [
    "tabs",
    "identity",
    "https://stackexchange.com/*/*"
  ],
  "options_ui": {
    "page": "options.html",
    "chrome_style": true
  },
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": {
      "19": "images/icon-19.png",
      "38": "images/icon-38.png"
    },
    "default_title": "someapp",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  }
}
```

EDIT : when I try to log the url on error, I have the following :

```
https://stackexchange.com/oauth/dialog?client_id=<client_id>&scope=read_inbox,no_expiry&redirect_uri=https://<app-id>.chromiumapp.org/oauth2#
```

but always the same error

Comment: Uhm, getRedirectURL expects a fully qualified URL...

Comment: Tried and failed: `encodeURIComponent` didn't help

Comment: It seems that this issue is related to this [one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29989155/error-cannot-return-to-provided-redirect-uri-in-chrome-extension-using-stackap).

Comment: Already read it before posting but I dont understand where I should put that url in "oauth domain configuration"

Answer (score 0):

I confronted the same issue as you today, and have been struggled a long time to finally get this problem solved.

I believe it's nothing wrong with what you have written in your code, but the options that you filled when you registered your app on stackexchange.com.

To be short, when you are filling out this form on https://stackapps.com/apps/oauth/register, always remember to write the correct form of the **OAuth Domain directive**, which should be:

`<app-id>.chromiumapp.org`

without protocol.

I solved this issue this way. Hope it's gonna help.